# R: Remove all data frames from work space that have 0 rows (i.e. are empty)

Tags: r, dataframe

I know this should be easy, but I am baffled on how to solve this problem.
I have a bunch of data frames, some are empty (0 rows, 42 variables), some have information in them (x rows, 42 variables) from a previous working step. I now simply want to delete all those with 0 rows.
First, I get all DF by

```
 alldfnames <- which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame)))
```

Second, I tried to write a function to distinguish between the data frames:

```
isFullDF <- function(x) dim(x)[1] > 0
```

Third, I tried to

```
  for (i in seq_along(alldfnames)) { 
     if(isFullDF(alldfnames[i]) == FALSE){
       rm(alldfnames[i])
    } else {
      # do nothing
   }
 }
```

But this gives me (for hours now) an error:

> Error in if (isFullDF(alldfnames[i]) == FALSE) { :
>     argument is of length zero

Any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
x <- eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame)
alldfnames <- names(x[x==T])
```

Now `alldfnames` contains all data frame names in your environment, then use the following function:

```
isFullDF <- function(nm) nrow(get(nm))>0
```

And then this one-line code instead of your `for` loop:

```
rm(list = alldfnames[!sapply(alldfnames, isFullDF)])
```

Answer (score 1):

First if you look at `alldfnames` you'll see it's a vector of integers where `names(alldfnames)` are the names of the variables you are after. So `alldfnames[i]` is just a number. So you need

```
alldfnames <- names(alldfnames)
```

which is a character vector of df names.

Next, when you do `dim(x)` and (e.g.) you have a dataframe called `df` in your enviromnent, `x` is  the *character* "df" not the *dataframe*. So you need to retrieve it. You can use `get` for that.

```
isFullDF <- function(x) nrow(get(x)) > 0
```

And then when you `rm` you need to tell R that the things you are removing are character strings with the *names* of the things you want to remove. As opposed to removing the object called `alldfnames[i]`. ie

```
rm(list=alldfnames[i])
```

(as an aside, you don't need the `else { }` if it's empty).

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my confusion about names and objects - I knew that was the problem, but could not find out what exactly. However, the last line

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. However, the last line rm(list =alldfnames[i]) does not delete any DF but gives the error message: In rm(list = alledfnamen[i]) : object 'NA' not found. What works is the last line from m0h3n: rm(list = alldfnames[!sapply(alldfnames, isFullDF)]). Could someone perhaps explain to me why? Anyway thanks to all for the fast help!!

Comment: `alldfnames[i]` must be `NA`. You will have to check why; there's no way for me to tell. Step through the code line by line and see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Filter`:

```
alldfnames = names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame))))

rowCounts = sapply(alldfnames,function(x) ifelse(nrow(get(x))==0,1,0))

emptyDF = names(Filter(function(f) f==1, rowCounts))

rm(list = emptyDF)
```